# use import via npm, do I need compiler?

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6

I am just curious, I installed jquery via npm locally, and created HTML code below

```
<body>
 <script>
    import jquery from "jquery";
 </script>
</body>
```

but it got error.
my browser is chrome v65 https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module The **import** is supported and doesn't need compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `type="module"` attribute on the `<script>` tag or else it won't know that you're trying to include ES6 modules. You do this by:

```
<script type="module">
</script>
```

Then the jQuery module from npm doesn't export anything by default, so you have to import the whole file like so:

```
<script type="module">
  import './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
</script>
```

So I'm importing everything from the jQuery file. Then what we get is the variable `jQuery` and the variable `$` assigned to the global `window` var.

Comment: I heard just mention the name of module work either, anyway it got error below: ailed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Good catch! My answer worked for me because I had an extension that injected jQuery . I edited my answer to something that should work!

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. I have error: jq/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Try `import * as $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: I got - Unexpected token *